# How to fix "SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try" in try/catch error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm completely new to javascript/nodejs and I'm just trying to add some error handling using try/catch to my script.

I've tried looking up examples on google/stackoverflow but I think I'm making a dumb syntax mistake because I can't get it to return the catch part successfully

```
const IncomingWebhook = require('@slack/webhook').IncomingWebhook; //function grabbed from slack webhook devkit library
var url = process.env.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL; //process SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL from env variables
var webhook = new IncomingWebhook(url);

const TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES = "10"
const GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS = "90"

// Send the notification, if no webhook is present in owners table, skips

if (url != ""){

    if (TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES != "0"){
        try {webhook.send({
            text: "*Daily Overdue Nessus Vulnerability Alert*",
            attachments: [{color: "#FF0000", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: "@here *" + TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES + "* Overdue Nessus Vulnerability issues reported \nOverdue Nessus Vulnerability GHE Issue Numbers: *" + GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS + "*"}}]}]
        });
        }
        .catch(err){
            console.log("Webhook Verification Failed");
        }
    }

    else {
        webhook.send({
            text: "*Daily Overdue Nessus Vulnerability Alert*",
            attachments: [{color: "#36a64f", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: "@here *NO* Overdue Nessus Vulnerabilities reported"}}]}]
        });
    }
}

else {console.log("No webhook provided");}
```

The try works as expected and so long as I give it a working webhook it will post successfully. The catch logic fails everytime (I just want it to post to console.log for the time being). If someone could help me fix my syntax I would appreciate it greatly

EDIT: I've tried replacing ".catch(err)" with "catch(error)" as suggested but it returns a different error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: A request error occurred: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80". I'm thinking webhook.send has a built in promise? I'm using https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/webhook

Comment: change `.catch` to `catch` - dont' confuse Promise .then/.catch and try/catch

Comment: `try { .... } catch (error) { ..... }`